# set input value equal to div content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I've a some dynamic buttons and when I click on them they display the price inside the div with `id="prezzo"`.

but now I need that, when I click on one of those buttons, they fill the hidden value field of the form with the same `"data-prezzo"`.

Basically I want that even the form value is dynamic like the div with `id="prezzo"`

Is this possible?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[id^=service]").on("click", getCheck);
  $(".event-hook-class").on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".event-hook-class").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active")
    $("#prezzo").html($(this).data('prezzo') + ' €');
    $("#form-prezzo").setAttribute("value", $(this).data('prezzo'));
    $("#piano").html('piano: ' + $(this).data('piano'));
    getCheck(); // will add this and the checkboxes
  });
  getCheck(); // initialise on page load
});
```

```html
<?php
  echo '<button type="button" class="event-hook-class simple-text piano" id="'.$id_appartamenti.'" data-prezzo="'.$prezzo_piano.'" data-piano="'.$piano.'">.$id_appartamenti.' <br> piano '.$piano.'<br> prezzo '.$prezzo_piano.' €</button><br>';
?>

<p class="paragraph" id="prezzo"> €</p>


<form>
<input type="hidden" value="" id="form-prezzo" data-name="prezzo">
</form>
```

and a form with this imput field

Comment: Hi where does `prova` comes from?

Comment: hi @t3__rry I've updated my question and correct the errors!

Comment: The PHP isn't relevant to your question so I removed the tag. Please update your code example and post the rendered HTML, not the PHP

Comment: It is relevant because the value has to be picked up from a "data" that is dynamically generated in php... however another user here just solved my question. thank you.

Comment: No, it's not relevant at all. Your PHP is processed on the server and the result it sent to the browser. The HTML and JavaScript is all that is relevant to this question.Everything PHP does is dynamically created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to set the input's value:

`$("#form-prezzo").val(prova)`

And also you have a double `id` attribute in you hidden field which is invalid

Comment: Sorry but i'm really new to js and i can't figure where to insert the [val()][1]

Comment: Sorry @StefanoZanetti I made a mistake in the formatting it was meant to be a link. Replace this line `$("#form-prezzo").setAttribute("value", $(this).data('prezzo'));`to this line `$("#form-prezzo").val( $(this).data('prezzo'));` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting the value of a div or p tag you can get it using the following code.

```
                 $("#prezzo").text()
```